# Howto call c++ member function as async call from QML

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, qml

I'm calling a `Q_INVOKABLE` member function from a `QML`. The GUI freezes until the function  is fully executed. I've some network operations going on in the invokable function therefore I want to GUI to continue exec and don't block for function to be completed.

QT documentation contains [WorkerScript QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-workerscript.html) but that doesn't fulfill my requirement as I cannot call invokable function inside .mjs file.

Is their a QT way of how to deal with such problem ?

PS: I've exposed my `C++` class to QML as below

```
Engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myClass", &obj);
```

And in the `qml`, I'm calling the member function as:

```
onTriggered: {
  
 myClass.myFunction( ... ); // This function needs to be executed async

}
```

Comment: Why is your network operation blocking? Don't you use `QIODevice::readyRead`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The async model does not exist in qml, this is why workerscript has been added.

To get a similar behavior on the c++ side, you would have to use QThread. To pass the results of your computation back to QML once the worker thread finish, you can, on the QML side, connect a callback to a given signal emitted by your class once the worker thread is done. To create the connection in QML, you might have to use the connection class [ https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html ], depending on how your c++ class is exposed to qml.

Comment: I've created a QThread, and set that as a member of myClass, call it inside the invokable function and it solved the problem. thanks